# How to deserialize only part of the json document?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

Using Json.Net on dotnet core v3 preview.

The json looks similar to:

```
{
    "rootElement": {
        "id": 500,
        "name": "water balloon"
    }
}
```

I would like to deserialize this into an object that looks like:

```
public class Item {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

instead of the much more annoying:

```
public class ItemWrapper {
    public Item rootElement {get;set;}
}
```

This is obviously a contrived example, but it illustrated the problem.  The actual `Item` class is far more complicated.  And there are many of them.  So I'm trying to identify a solution that will work for any json document that has this general format with a root node followed by the object I am actually interested in.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just use `JObject.Parse`? e.g. `var obj = JObject.Parse("json"); var item = obj["rootElement"].ToObject<Item>();`

Comment: @zaitsman: perfect.  Thank you very much.  If you write it up as an answer we can close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JObject.Parse` from `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace, and get your item like so:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("json"); 
var item = obj["rootElement"].ToObject<Item>();
```

Comment: Please don’t answer duplicate questions. A very cursory search on the title brought up several.